Imported Linux raid (raid 5) assembled ok but cannot access data
This setup is a little convoluted.
I have images of three 8TB drives from another Linux system that contain an md raid-5 setup.
I have mounted these images as physical drives in windows (physicaldrive5, 6 , 7).
I have added these to a VMware workstation as readonly physical drives with a Linux Mint guest OS.
After booting into Mint on the VM I can successfully assemble the raid (read only) on /dev/md0.
However any attempt to read the data on /dev/md0 results in a input/output error.
$ sudo mdadm -A -R -o --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 3 drives.
$ ls /proc/mdstat
/proc/mdstat
$ cat !$
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active (read-only) raid5 sdb1[0](F) sdd1[3](F) sdc1[1](F)
      15627786240 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/0] [___]
      bitmap: 0/59 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
$ sudo mdadm --detail --test /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Dec  2 22:16:42 2022
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 15627786240 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813893120 (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Mar 19 14:28:36 2024
             State : clean, FAILED 
    Active Devices : 0
    Failed Devices : 3
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed

       0       8       17        -      faulty   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        -      faulty   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        -      faulty   /dev/sdd1
$ sudo file /dev/md0
/dev/md0: block special (9/0)
$ hexdump /dev/md0 | more
hexdump: /dev/md0: Input/output error
$ 

I can see the status is not clean. Do I need to clean this?
Any tips on what I might be doing wrong or how to access this raid appreciated.

I note that all three drives are showing in the Failed devices category and appear as faulty in the drive list. It's refusing to read because it has nothing it trusts to read from. What steps have you taken to resolve that?

Can you check if you are able to read from the sd[b,c,d] devices?  Edit your question and add the output of sudo hexdump /dev/sdb |hexdump -C |head -10 and the output of lsblk /dev/sd[b-d].

@MirceaVutcovici confirm I can dump the data from the three individual drives.  I can also perform a mdadm --examine /dev/sd[b-d] and get the expected results.

@tsc_chazz At this stage because I can only access the drives read only, nothing.  I am attempting to add a VMware write extent to the virtual drives to provide write access.

I was unable to get the Linux raid drive mounted under Linux but found a tool under windows that did the job.  The drives were all good and all the data was intact. I have to concluded the problem under Linux was because the drives were read-only this causes issues that doesn't allow the raid driver to accept those drives.
